# PLease explain stat_summary inheritance?

Tags: r, ggplot2, summary, stat

I'm new to ggplot2 and don't really understand how inheritance works. I'm trying to create a line plot of sums of 4 types of air pollution across time:

```
## Download dataset to local directory and read into dataframes
if(!file.exists("./pm25")){dir.create("./pm25")}
setwd("./pm25")
fileUrl<-"https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/exdata%2Fdata%2FNEI_data.zip"
download.file(fileUrl,destfile="./pm25data.zip",method="curl")
unzip("pm25data.zip")
NEI<-readRDS("summarySCC_PM25.rds")

## Subset Baltimore data for 1999 and 2008 and reclassify 'year' and 'type' as factors
NEIsubBalt<-subset(NEI,NEI$fips=="24510"&(NEI$year==1999|NEI$year==2008))
NEIsubBalt$year<-as.factor(NEIsubBalt$year)
NEIsubBalt$type<-as.factor(NEIsubBalt$type)

## Load ggplot2 library and build plot
library(ggplot2)
png("plot2.png",width=480,height=480)
   g<-ggplot(NEIsubBalt,aes(year,Emissions),mapping=aes(group=type,color=type))
      g+ggtitle("Total PM2.5 Emissions for Baltimore by Type")  
      g+stat_summary(aes(year,Emissions),fun.y="sum",geom="line",lwd=1,inherit.aes=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

This creates the line plot but overwrites the title:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Av2W.png)
If I try to add the title after creating the line plot, it overwrites the plot. Can someone please explain how this function works and can be used in the chaining of calls that makes ggplot so useful? Thanks!

Comment: Here, you're doing `g+ggtitle(...) `, which outputs the plot, but doesn't store the output in a variable. You would need `g <- g + ggtitle(...) `. Or you just chain them from the initial call. `g <- ggplot(...) + ggtitle(...) + stat_summary(...)`

Comment: Ah! I was thinking that + just added the new call to the plot... thanks for clarifying!